# SQL Server : trigger error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Could someone solve this please:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_admin_ForInsert
ON admin
FOR INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE adminID INT
    SELECT adminID = adminID from inserted

    insert into adminAudit 
    Values ('New Admin with ID = ' + Cast (ID as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' is added at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR (20)))
END
```

I get the error message:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure tr_admin_ForInsert, Line 7
>   'INT' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

- `INT` is underlined and says '"is not a recognized CURSOR option'
- `SELECT` is underlined and says 'Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'. Expecting CURSOR, or ID

This is my inserted table for admin:

```
USE [zachtravelagency]
CREATE TABLE admin
(
        [adminID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        [firstname] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        [surname] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        [username] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
        [password] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);
```

This is my inserted table for adminAudit:

```
CREATE table adminAudit 
(
      [adminAuditID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
      [AuditData] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: prefix your declaration with `@` symbol, i.e.
`DECLARE adminID INT` should be `DECLARE @adminID INT`

Comment: Unless you are absolutely sure that there will only ever be one admin inserted at a time then this will work; the triggers operate on sets though so doing something like `SELECT @adminID = adminID from inserted` is doomed to fail as the statement might return more than one record.

Comment: And to add to what @jpw you can't ever be absolutely certain that will be the case. I know a guy who was a consultant at a company that literally went under because they had triggers everywhere that couldn't handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a variable at all.  Use `insert . . . select`:

```
BEGIN 

    insert into adminAudit 
        select 'New Admin with ID = ' + Cast (adminid as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' is added at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR(20))
        from inserted;
END
```

I would also suggest the following:

- Use `convert()` so you have control over the date format.
- Better yet, use separate columns in the `Audit` table for the id, the date, and the operation that you are doing.  Putting everything in a string seems inefficient and difficult for investigation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

prefix your declaration with `@` symbol

Update your trigger with this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tr_admin_ForInsert
    ON admin
    FOR INSERT 
    AS 
    BEGIN 

    DECLARE @adminID INT
    SELECT @adminID = adminID from inserted

    insert into adminAudit 
    Values ('New Admin with ID = ' + Cast (ID as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' is added at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR (20)))
```

Comment: While this would "fix" the problem it will generate a mountain of new ones. Scalar variables in a trigger mean the trigger is unable to handle multiple row operations. This should instead be a set based approach.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `@` before variable and pass appropriate value from `inserted` 
i.e. i. `i.adminID from inserted i`

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_admin_ForInsert
    ON admin
    FOR INSERT 
    AS 
    BEGIN 

    DECLARE @adminID INT;
    SELECT @adminID = i.adminID from inserted i

    insert into adminAudit 
    Values ('New Admin with ID = ' + Cast (@adminID as NVARCHAR(5)) + ' is added at ' + cast(Getdate() as NVARCHAR (20)))
```

Comment: While this would "fix" the problem it will generate a mountain of new ones. Scalar variables in a trigger mean the trigger is unable to handle multiple row operations. This should instead be a set based approach.